# Updateview does not restrict only to the id of the logged in user

Tags: django, django-views

I am using UpdateView, but I need only that when the user that is logged in can change, just the photo of it.
As it is now if I type in the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-photo/26/ it changes the photo of the user 26, even though I am logged in with the user 12
I want only the logged in user to be able to change their photo and not the photos of other users

View.py

```
class PhotoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model= Usuario  
    fields = ['foto']
    template_name='change-photo.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('sistema_index')
```

url.py

```
 url(r'^change-photo/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PhotoUpdate.as_view(), 
     name='sistema_change_photo'),
```

change-photo.html

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.usuario.pk }}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'sistema_change_photo' user.usuario.pk%}" class="form-signin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-row "> 
<div class="form-group col-md-12 ">

    {{ form.foto }}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row"> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">

</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your **views.py** as below.

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin    # Mixin that redirect user to login if not authenticated

class PhotoUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model= Usuario  
    fields = ['foto']
    template_name='change-photo.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()   # This should help to get current user 

        # Next, try looking up by primary key of Usario model.
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user)


        try:
            # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
            obj = queryset.get()
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("No user matching this query")
        return obj


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('sistema_index')
```

Inside your **urls.py** file

```
url(r'^change-photo/$', views.PhotoUpdate.as_view(), 
     name='sistema_change_photo'),
```

Comment: my friend erro
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'

Comment: replace `queryset = queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user)` with `queryset = queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what error code you want when trying to access another users photo.

If a 404 is acceptable then the easiest way is to restrict the QuerySet the user is allowed to operate on. 
Something like this but edit to what you named your user-foreignkey field

```
class PhotoUpdate(UpdateView):

     ...

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Usuario.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

If you rather return a permission denied you want to add a permission class to the view.

Comment: perfect friend, but now when I put the menu in the a 
`'class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'sistema_change_photo' %}">Trocar Foto</a>'`

erro

`Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /perfil/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'sistema_change_photo' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['change-photo/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$', 'sistema\\/change-photo/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

Comment: Its telling you there is no URL named sistema_change_photo that takes 0 arguments, both your urls take 1 argument, which is the (?P<pk>\\d+) part of the url, you need to use {% url 'sistema_change_photo' photo.pk %} or similar to give it an ID

Comment: save for my life